# Can't use GPU on Google colab in conda environment (Tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, conda, google-colaboratory

I made a short `Colab` Notebook to simulate the situation on my local PC where I use `conda / mamba` and can't get any `GPU` working for `tensorflow`. I know `colab` can do this out of the box, but that's not, what I want to do. I'm also quite new to `colab` and still trying to figure out, how it's used :D.

So here's my Code for `colab`:

```
# Install Miniconda
!curl -O https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
!sh Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -f -p /usr/local

# Set channels
!conda config --add channels defaults
!conda config --add channels bioconda
!conda config --add channels conda-forge

# Install Mamba
!conda install -y mamba
```

next cell:

```
# Create Environment
!mamba create -y -n stats-gpu tensorflow-gpu cudatoolkit cudnn
```

I also tried:

```
!mamba create -n stats-gpu python=3.8 tensorflow-gpu=2.4 cudnn=8.0 cudatoolkit=11.0
```

next cell:

```
# simulate "conda activate" by setting PYTHONPATH and PATH
import sys
import os
PYTHONPATH = os.environ['PYTHONPATH']
sys.path = ['',
            PYTHONPATH,
            '/usr/local/envs/stats-gpu/lib/python37.zip',
            '/usr/local/envs/stats-gpu/lib/python3.7',
            '/usr/local/envs/stats-gpu/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
            '/usr/local/envs/stats-gpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
os.environ['PATH'] = ('/usr/local/envs/stats-gpu/bin:' +
                      '/usr/local/condabin:' +
                      os.environ['PATH'])
```

next cell:

```
# Executing directly in cell will ignore python installed by conda.
# Writing Python script in .py file and executing with !python will use
# Python from conda.
filename = "tensortest.py"
with open(filename, 'w') as file:
    file.write("""import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))""")
!python tensortest.py
```

The output is

```
Num GPUs Available:  0
```

but it should be 1. Why is that? The GPU in `colab` is active and works when I just use

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

in an empty Notebook.

Comment: Hi @gernophil! Could you try again without a conda environment and changing Runtime to GPU from "Runtime " tab at top of colab. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, have you found the solution? i am facing similar. Without using conda, it is able to detect GPU. but with conda, it couldn't